# regression in Qt between 4.7 and 4.8

Tags: qt4, pyqt

This is probably regression between Qt4.7 and Qt4.8. Each paragraph should be on separate line, but on 4.8 it's broken. Do you know about some workaround for this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class CustomLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(CustomLabel, self).__init__(text)
        self._text = text

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        brect = QRect()  #Qt.rect()
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(brect, Qt.transparent)
        doc = QTextDocument(self)
        stylesheet = "*{color: " + painter.pen().color().name() + "; line-height:0.3; margin:0; padding:0;}"
        doc.setDefaultStyleSheet(stylesheet)
        doc.setUndoRedoEnabled(False)
        doc.setHtml(self._text)
        doc.setUseDesignMetrics(True)
        doc.drawContents(painter, QRectF())
        print(doc.toHtml())
        print(doc.toPlainText())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label = CustomLabel("<p><font style=\"font-size: 9px;\" color=\"#fffe51\">Text 2</font></p><p><font size=\"9px\" color=\"#aaaaaa\">Text 3</font></p>")
label.show()
label.resize(100, 100)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify a `line-height` of `0.3` without giving a unit. The documentation [says this about length units](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#length):

> A number followed by a measurement unit. The CSS standard recommends that user agents must ignore a declaration with an illegal value. In Qt, it is mandatory to specify measurement units. For compatibility with earlier versions of Qt, numbers without measurement units are treated as pixels in most contexts.

It doesn't however say exactly in which contexts it's interpreted as pixels and in which it isn't. Probably there was a change how it was interpreted in the context of `line-height`.

`line-heigth` is [one of the more recently added features](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/merge_requests/2305), so compatibility with earlier version probably isn't considered an issue here.

(Actually, I've just seen that `line-height` isn't even officially mentioned in the style sheet reference.)

Comment: Thank you, it seems that removing line-height fixed the issue